# macOS Homebrew - How to remove sonarqube and keep data for sonarqube-lts?

Tags: macos, sonarqube, homebrew

For unknown reasons I managed to install **both** `sonarqube` and `sonarqube-lts` Homebrew packages (which shouldn't be possible, as they are marked to "conflict with each other").

When I try to upgrade my outdated packages, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot install sonarqube because conflicting formulae are installed.
  sonarqube-lts: because both install the same binaries

Please `brew unlink sonarqube-lts` before continuing.
```

The thing is, I want to *keep* `sonarqube-lts`, and remove `sonarqube`. I tried `brew unlink sonarqube` but it didn't work.

Question: How do I remove `sonarqube` from my system - Important: **I want to keep all existing data of the package**, so `uninstall` is probably the wrong command.